# In kubernetes, is there a way to make statefulset pods linger to finish requests on rolling update?

Tags: kubernetes, sharding, kubernetes-statefulset

In Kubernetes, I have a statefulset with a number of replicas.
I've set the updateStrategy to RollingUpdate.
I've set podManagementPolicy to Parallel.
My statefulset instances do not have a persistent volume claim -- I use the statefulset as a way to allocate ordinals 0..(N-1) to pods in a deterministic manner.

The main reason for this, is to keep availability for new requests while rolling out software updates (freshly built containers) while still allowing each container, and other services in the cluster, to "know" its ordinal.

The behavior I want, when doing a rolling update, is for the previous statefulset pods to linger while there are still long-running requests processing on them, but I want new traffic to go to the new pods in the statefulset (mapped by the ordinal) without a temporary outage.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way of doing this -- what am I missing?

Because I don't use volume claims, you might think I could use deployments instead, but I really do need each of the pods to have a deterministic ordinal, that:

- is unique at the point of dispatching new service requests (incoming HTTP requests, including public ingresses)
- is discoverable by the pod itself
- is persistent for the duration of the pod lifetime
- is contiguous from 0 .. (N-1)

The second-best option I can think of is using something like zookeeper or etcd to separately manage this property, using some of the traditional long-poll or leader-election mechanisms, but given that kubernetes already knows (or can know) about all the necessary bits, AND kubernetes service mapping knows how to steer incoming requests from old instances to new instances, that seems more redundant and complicated than necessary, so I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you need this for a *stateful workload*, a workload that e.g. requires writes. Otherwise you can use Deployments with multiple pods online for your shards. A key feature with StatefulSet is that they provide **unique stable network identities** for the instances.

> The behavior I want, when doing a rolling update, is for the previous statefulset pods to linger while there are still long-running requests processing on them, but I want new traffic to go to the new pods in the statefulset.

This behavior is supported by Kubernetes pods. But you also need to implement support for it in your application.

- New traffic will not be sent to your "old" pods.
- A `SIGTERM` signal will be sent to the pod - your application may want to listen to this and do some action.
- After a *configurable* "termination grace period", your pod will get killed.

See [Kubernetes best practices: terminating with grace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) for more info about pod termination.

Be aware that you should connect to *services* instead of directly to *pods* for this to work. E.g. you need to create [headless services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for the replicas in a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

If your clients are connecting to a specific *headless service*, e.g. `N`, this means that it will not be available for some times during upgrades. You need to decide if your clients should **retry** their connections during this time period *or* if they should connect to another *headless service* if `N` is not available.

If you are in a case where you need:

- stateful workload (e.g. support for write operations)
- want high availability for your instances

then you need a form of distributed system that does some form of replication/synchronization, e.g. using [raft](https://raft.github.io/) or a product that implements this. Such system is easiest deployed as a StatefulSet.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't fulfill the "stable key to pod mapping" property. Services (even headless services) are not consistent key partitioned.

Comment: "this means that it will not be available for some times during upgrades" Also this is exactly what I need to not happen. New replica comes up for partition N, new traffic goes to that, while old traffic drains.

Comment: @JonWatte no, the headless service is the proper way a StatefulSet use for managing unique network identities, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations

Comment: @JonWatte "Also this is exactly what I need to not happen" what you say here is impossible, since you want **unique** indentities. StatefulSet guarantees this, and to terminate the old pod before creating a new is the only way to guarantee this **uniqueness**. Perhaps you are looking for other behavior than what StatefulSet guarantees. You could write your own controller to create a different behavior.

Comment: @JonWatte I expanded my answer to elaborate about replicate (if you have stateful workload) or Deployment as alternative if you have a stateless workload.

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. There are still three things I don't understand:
1) How can a Deployment "sense" which ordinal it is? It doesn't seem to be available in downstream API.
2) The documentation for StatefulSet says the pods will finish to termination before the next one is started; your description of SIGTERM contradicts this. Which is right?
3) You suggest clients will see unavailability; I want to avoid this, and headless services do not use Kube-proxy so they can't automatically move (must use DNS.)

Comment: Also, yes, it may be that the uniqueness I want is approximately "uniqueness in kube-proxy routing for new requests" plus the stable ID, whereas the uniqueness that statefulset guarantees is the stronger "unique process identified by the ordinal" and to guarantee the latter variant, there has to be downtime.

Comment: On 2) there seem to be a misunderstanding. I wrote only for a single pod. It is correct that StatefulSet fully terminates an instance before a new comes up - otherwise it cannot hold the uniqueness property. It sounds like you want the **unique identity** and **high availability** - it is not something that is provided out of the box from Kubernetes, it needs to be implemented in the application using e.g. Raft, so you need multiple replicas per shard to achieve this. The last part of my answer describes this.

Comment: To clarify: I need *almost unique* identity. I e, it's OK that the identity overlaps during the update/deployment window, when the "old" copy is in "draining" state. As you suggest, I pretty much need a new kind of controller for this, or some other arbitrator in front (such as swapping labels around that end up mapping to service endpoint sets.)

Comment: Your service is stateful, right? e.g. there are writes to it, or is it stateful in some other way? Or are there only reads, and can be considered a stateless service?

Comment: To answer @Jonas comment: It is stateful-ish. I'd like the old instance to finish serving writes that already started, in parallel with sending new writes to the new instance. E g, I need sequenced switch-over. Because there are many clients, I need positive confirmation from the old one that it's in "shutdown" mode before I can tell the new one to enter "ready" mode, which means clients may see a short time of unavailability, which in turn means clients must be prepared to re-try. I don't think there's a better approach without involving something much heavier in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this using [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/), specifically the `preStop` hook.

We use this to drain connections from our Varnish service before it terminates.

However, you would need to implement (or find) a script to do the draining.

Comment: How does this perform the "stable key to pod mapping" function?

Comment: A stateful set has a known naming convention. They will always been named {stateful-set-name}-X where X is an incrementing number. If you delete that pod, another will be create with the same name to replace it.

Comment: Yes, but how do I roll out new software and get new requests routed to the new container, without terminating currently outstanding requests previously routed to the old container? What would I do in the preStop hook to make this work?

Comment: When you roll out an update on a statefulset, Kubernetes will (normally, at least from my observations) terminate and update one pod at a time. As mentioned in my answer you can use the lifecycle hook to do a connection draining on your service before it terminates -- this will resolve your "without terminating currently outstanding requests"  question. Since your pod is considered "terminating" at this stage, it would not be getting any new requests. As for how to do the connection draining, something like this: https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2017-October/026204.html